# How do treasure tokens work?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

Some of the encounter cards in *Wrath of Ashardalon* have you put a treasure token on a tile. How do the adventurers pick up a treasure token? What can we do with the treasure tokens? They are worth gold, but I don't see anything to buy. Is it just for bragging rights?

P.S. Can someone with more rep than me create a "dnd-wrath-of-ashardalon" tag and add it to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miguel's answer is largely correct. However, there are also rules for handling treasure tokens in an adventure that doesn't use treasure tokens. In [the same rules](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Wrath_Ashardalon_RuleBook.pdf), page 16, the FAQ tells you how to handle events that refer to treasure tokens when you're not using them:

> **Dragon’s Tribute (59):** If you aren’t using the Treasure Tokens in this adventure, draw 2 Treasure Cards and select the one with the lower gold piece (gp) value. If the values are the same, pick the one that you want.
>
> **Hidden Treasure (70):** If you aren’t using the Treasure Tokens in this adventure and you draw this card, draw and place a Treasure Card on the tile. A Hero that ends his or her Hero Phase on the tile can claim the Treasure Card.

Answer (score 4):

From the rulebook ([source](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Wrath_Ashardalon_RuleBook.pdf)), under optional rules (page 15):

> **Monster and Treasure Tokens**
>   Some Adventures use Monster or Treasure tokens to add an element of surprise or risk to a particular scenario. The Adventure explains how to use the tokens and when they are needed.

If an adventure gives no explanation for their use, then yes, they simply give the players bragging rights.